# Parsing a data file into a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, file, parsing

I'm working on parsing a file in Python, all files will look something like this:

```
100
3
(5.0000, 0.0000, 3.5000, 501.0000)
(4.8831, 1.0749, 3.4416, 23.2251)
(4.5379, 2.0994, 3.2689, 12.6309)
```

Where the first value is the number of data points, the second is a certain type of flag, and the rest of the values are data points.

So far I've been able to parse all the file data into the array using:

```
lines = tuple(open(str(sys.argv[1]) , 'r')
```

But where my trouble comes in is parsing the data  after I've gotten it in that array.

I'm trying to make an array that just contains the data after the first two lines that just contain the numbers in a 2d array without the `(`, `,`, `)` and just the number data.

EDIT: I should mention that the data does not have to be a decimal number, it could be an int as well.

Comment: You just want to remove all of the `(` and `,` and `)`?

Comment: Basically, yes but I'd also like to add the data to a 2d array, where as now it is in a 1d array as a whole string.

Comment: Well, seems like they can be normal Python tuples, maybe read them as tuples will be better than use regex here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
skip = 2
with open('path/to/infile') as infile:
    for _ in range(skip):
        infile.readline()
    answer = [[float(num) for num in line.strip()[1:-1].split(',')] for line in infile]
```

Comment: If the number in the data is not a float it gives me an error. the data can be in float or int, is there a way to make it so that it'll account for both possibilities?

Comment: That should be able to handle ints just fine. I think the error you're facing comes from somewhere else. If you show me the error, I might be able to fix it

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cluster.py", line 31, in <module>
    answer = [[float(num) for num in line[:1-2].split(',')] for line in infile]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: (1`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the way you do it right now is messy and won't work generally.

Try something like this:

```
filename = sys.argv[1] #no need to str(), it's already one
array = [] #initialize empty
with open(filename) as f: #automatically closes file
    next(f) #ignore first line
    flag = next(f) # get next line. maybe int() it?
    for line in f: #for remaining file:
        noparens = line[1:-2] #remove first and last character (and newline too)
        numbers = map(float, noparens.split(","))) #split and convert to float
        array.append(list(numbers)) #append array to outer array
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'm try this and see how it works out, then let you kow.